# External Table in snowflake should read and point to the latest files created in Azure data lake storage automatically

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When everytime my azure pipeline runs a new files gets created in azure data lake storage, so now I want my external table already created for this table to point to the latest file created in data lake

I have multiple parquet files of the same table in blob storage, we want to read the latest parquet file in external table in snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [this section](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-azure.html) in the Snowflake documentation. It covers the steps required to configure Automatic Refresh of External Tables using Azure Event Grid. If this is not suitable for your use case, can you provide more detail on your issue and why.